Spring Boot - spring-web-flow with spring-boot-starter-web and Thymeleaf new example?
I've been looking for a simple example of a Spring Boot project that contains the following:

spring-web-flow
spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

The only new example I've found with spring-web-flow v.3.0.0 is:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow-samples/tree/main/booking-mvc
But,I was hoping to find something simpler. Does anybody know if there are other simple examples?
https://spring.io/projects/spring-webflow
